# Magento 2 - Admin 'Content' grids not showing (Fresh Magento Installation on MAC OS)

Tags: magento2, grid

I'm wondering if anyone can point me into the right direction. I am using a 2015 Macbook Pro, running the latest Mac OS version. I'm trying to set up a Magento 2 locally using MAMP / Phpmyadmin / apache2.

I've installed Magento 2 via Composer into my MAMP directory and it's passed the readiness check regarding php versions etc and successfully installed.

The frontend appears to be working fine. When I however go into the admin panel, for example (Catalog -> Products, Catalog -> Categories), (Content -> Pages / blocks), and even Content -> Design -> Config (anything with a grid view), it's just completely blank with no grid. When I try add a new block, new page or new category etc.. it just refreshes the page.

I've tried installing Magento 2.3.4 and even 2.3.3 (to see if it was a latest version issue), and also tried installing a Magento with sample data. The sample data shows up in the Catalog->Categories for example, but when I click on a category in the left hand side, it's still not showing the main grid on the page with all the tabs for the content.

I've checked file and folder permissions, re-compiled the site, flushed the cache. Etc. There is absolutely nothing in apache error log and the only errors inside magento logs are:

[image: magento 2 broken product grid in admin]

```
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_ratings was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_pending was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_customer was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_product was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CheckoutAgreements::sales_checkoutagreement was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Braintree::settlement_report was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_UrlRewrite::urlrewrite was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sitemap::catalog_sitemap was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rules was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rates was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_TaxImportExport::system_convert_tax was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::automation_studio was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::exclusion_rules was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::marketing_automation_report was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::dashboards was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::importer was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::automation was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::campaign was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::cron was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::logviewer was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Dotdigitalgroup_Email::abandoned was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::shipping was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::carriers was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::locations was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::packaging was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::experiences was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::pickups was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::dispatches was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::batches was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:47] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::product was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:48] main.INFO: Add of item with id Yotpo_Yotpo::yotpo_report_reviews was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:48] main.INFO: Add of item with id Yotpo_Yotpo::yotpo_reviews_external was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:48] main.INFO: Add of item with id Yotpo_Yotpo::yotpo_analytics_external was processed [] []
[2020-02-25 13:15:48] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/devfinal/project-community-edition/admin/cms/block/index/key/dc7b1b5abeab225862f1df4ab4409f63762298e52700f85a2c72dffd2288ca9e/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_4fcf954951acbd49b0486d818717586eb0d7e95e"}} []
[2020-02-25 13:15:48] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/devfinal/project-community-edition/admin/cms/block/index/key/dc7b1b5abeab225862f1df4ab4409f63762298e52700f85a2c72dffd2288ca9e/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_2c670632b618da13b396fd84287d8ae9598c0b07"}} []
[2020-02-25 13:17:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/devfinal/project-community-edition/admin/catalog/category/add/key/a7275d02ab4b2203c4932e37daf26330c29128281c6ed6dd48dfa68a38174535/store/0/parent/1","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_d9f284034dbc083441b715d66da7a5a77eed4c16"}} []
```

Could someone shed some light as to what I could possibly be doing wrong or have I missed a step in the installation process? (The only thing I've done is installed the site via composer, create the db table and ran through installation in the browser). I've only ever setup Magento 2's on work servers which are using Nginx instead of Apache.

is it possible that something else isn't configured properly on my MAC?

Tia

Comment: Have you run CLI deploy and compile after installing via composer?

Comment: @Agilox Yeah I have

Comment: How did you configure your host? Or just install on localhost directory? Do you browse your site on http://localhost/devfinal/project-community-edition/ URL?

Comment: @Agilox Yeah I just installed Magento 2 via CLI. went into Applications/MAMP/Htdocs/devfinal and ran composer create project (as defined in Magento docs). and Yeah I access the site via localhost/devfinal/project-community-edition - Frontend is all working fine but I'm unable to make any categories or products in the admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 backend authentication does not work on the top-level domains like localhost. You can create a virtual host and install Magento on it. If you search "how to setup virtual host on mamp", you can find help how to configure virtual host. After configuring virtual host (alternative of localhost), you can install Magento on its directory using composer.

Comment: Ah great. I remember doing something similar actually in a previous job about a year ago, but using MAMP Pro to assist with the virtual host.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The missing content is loaded in ajax, check your network tab and search for a request like `mui/indexer/render`.

You should find this type of request :
`<magento_admin_url>/mui/index/render/?namespace=product_listing&<other_params>`

Do you have any JS error in your browser console ?